# Website detects selenium despite trying a lot of measures

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I have a toolset for (ebay) kleinanzeigen.de to post and delete old adds. Lastweek everything worked fine. As I wanted to use the script today it didn't work anymore.

Even without any automated action they block you.

try this code. It just opens a window and kleinanzeigen.de

```py
from selenium import webdriver
import time
Driverpath="C:\your path the driver/chromedriver.exe"

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/119.0.0.0 Safari/537.36")
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(Driverpath,options=options)
driver.execute_cdp_cmd("Page.addScriptToEvaluateOnNewDocument", {
    "source":
        "const newProto = navigator.__proto__;"
        "delete newProto.webdriver;"
        "navigator.__proto__ = newProto;"
    })
driver.execute_cdp_cmd("Page.addScriptToEvaluateOnNewDocument", {
"source": """
    Object.defineProperty(navigator, 'webdriver', {
    get: () => null
    })
"""
})

driver.maximize_window()

driver.get("https://www.kleinanzeigen.de")
time.sleep(1)
driver.execute_script('window.key = \"ASSH\";"')
```

Try then to login with your account. You have to use a slider and after that you get a message that you have been blocked. Opening a normal chrome, not controlled by selenium is no problem, you can login there. So it is not a problem with IP-Adress.

Also tried with selenium stealth as suggested in this thread [Can a website detect when you are using Selenium with chromedriver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33225947/can-a-website-detect-when-you-are-using-selenium-with-chromedriver). Didn't help neither. As you can see I also used other workarounds recommended in this thread.

Any ideas what they do and how to prevent it? It is really annoying creating Ads by hand. I mean they provide no API thats so oldschool, so you are more or less forced using selenium.

I also used `perl -pi -e 's/cdc_/ash_/g' chromedriver.exe` and using this driver with code above, but that also doesn't help.

Comment: To be clear, you need to login to the site? Have you tried [undetected chromedriver](https://pypi.org/project/undetected-chromedriver/)?

Comment: I've considered but unfortunately this project is currently not working or only with Chrome <= 116 which I don't want to use because of security issues https://github.com/ultrafunkamsterdam/undetected-chromedriver/issues/1589